# How to put two icon-prefixed input fields in side-by-side columns with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I figured you would simply do `col-sm-6` on each of the `input-group-addon` classed elements, but no dice.  Wrapping didn't work either.

Here's a Fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/s6Xu6/368/

Here's what I'm trying to do:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take a look at bootstrap [grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)

The Bootstrap grid system has four classes:

**xs** (for phones - screens less than 768px wide)
**sm** (for tablets - screens equal to or greater than 768px wide)
**md** (for small laptops - screens equal to or greater than 992px wide)
**lg** (for laptops and desktops - screens equal to or greater than 1200px wide)

and if you need to make the the grid available on all screen size you can use the smallest one xs

so for your code using xs will work on all screens

```
<div class='col-sm-12'>
  <div class='col-xs-6'>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Price"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-xs-6'>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Price"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just so you know... `col-` shouldn't be placed directly in another `col-`. Nesting like this requires another `row`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-nesting